# VBA-PPT change color of Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, colors, hyperlink, powerpoint

I'm trying to change the color of all Hyperlinks in my PowerPoint presenation.

This was my first try:

```
Sub ChangeShapeColor()

Dim oHl As Hyperlinks
Dim oSl As Slide

' Look at each slide in the current presentation:
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

    ' Look at each shape on each slide:
    For Each oHl In oSl.Shapes

        ' IF the shape's .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = black color:
        If oHl.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            ' Change it to corporate yellow:
            oHl.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 235, 26)
        End If

    Next oHl
Next oSl

End Sub
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Well, what happened on your first try?

Comment: Debugger told me something is wrong with the "Fill" Argument.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using .Font.Color = RGB(242, 235, 26)?

Answer (score 1):

To adjust all of the hyperlink colors, you change the color scheme, specifically the 11th and 12th slots in the scheme, which are the ones that control the hyperlink colors.

Here's an example that sets the hyperlink and followed hyperlink colors to green and red, respectively:

```
Sub SetHyperlinkColors()
    With ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme
        ' Hyperlink color
        .Colors(11).RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        ' Followed hyperlink color
        .Colors(12).RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

That's the simplified version. It only acts on the first Design (ie, Master) in the presentation. If you have more than one design, you'd do something like this, which will also work on presentations with only one design:

```
Sub SetHyperlinkColors()
    Dim x as Long
    With ActivePresentation
        For x = 1 to .Designs.Count
            With .Designs(x).SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme
                ' Hyperlink color
                .Colors(11).RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                ' Followed hyperlink color
                .Colors(12).RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)   
            End With ' Designs(x)
        Next  ' Design
    End with
End Sub
```